# Add new items to a new list

Tags: c#, json

I want to end up here with `FAQData` being a JSON string. First, I have this simple class:

```
public class FAQData
{
    public string FAQQuestion { get; set; }
    public string FAQAnswer { get; set; }
}
```

And then, this is where I'm not sure how to handle it...

```
var faqData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new List<FAQData>
    {
        {
           FAQQuestion = "Question 1?",
           FAQAnswer = "This is the answer to Question 1."
        },
        {
           FAQQuestion = "Question 2?",
           FAQAnswer = "This is the answer to Question 2."
        },
    })
```

Obviously the above syntax isn't correct.  I've been playing around and trying various google searched, but I can't seem to get there.  What I want is for `FAQData` JSON string result to look like this:

```
[ 
    {"FAQQuestion": "Question 1?", "FAQAnswer": "This is the answer to Question 1."},
    {"FAQQuestion": "Question 2?", "FAQAnswer": "This is the answer to Question 2."}
]
```

Comment: Do you mean you want the output to be
[
    {"FAQQuestion": "Question 1?", "FAQAnswer": "This is the answer to Question 1."},
    {"FAQQuestion": "Question 2?", "FAQAnswer": "This is the answer to Question 2."}
]

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot `new FAQData()`:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new List<FAQData>
{
    new FAQData()
    {
        FAQQuestion = "Question 1?",
        FAQAnswer = "This is the answer to Question 1."
    },
    new FAQData()
    {
        FAQQuestion = "Question 2?",
        FAQAnswer = "This is the answer to Question 2."
    },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a variable list to manipulate, before serializing to JSON.

```
            var faqList = new List<FAQData>
            {
                new FAQData()
                {
                   FAQQuestion = "Question 1?",
                   FAQAnswer = "This is the answer to Question 1."
                },
                new FAQData()
                {
                   FAQQuestion = "Question 2?",
                   FAQAnswer = "This is the answer to Question 2."
                },
            };
            faqList.Add(new FAQData()
            {
                FAQQuestion = "Question 3?",
                FAQAnswer = "This is the answer to Question 3."
            });
            var faqData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(faqList);
```